# why is my avatar broken?

Tags: support, profile-picture

My profile shows this:

[image]

but the toolbar shows this:

[image]

It looks like the 24-pixel generated mini-avatar on imgur is broken:

[image]

but other sizes are OK:

[image]

I realize that this is probably an imgur bug, but I thought it was worthwhile posting it in case other people have this problem. Uploading it again fixed it.

Comment: Try re-uploading it. That might solve the problem.

Comment: searching didn't bring up that duplicate. oh well.

Comment: No problem. I also didn't find it using search, I found it while looking at all [tag:imgur] questions because I knew it was there.

Comment: i didn't know to use the 'profile-picture' tag in the search. i searched for 'avatar'. with your tag editing privs, maybe you could add a synonym?

Comment: I have the rep, but I don't have the tag score to propose a synonym for that tag. And I actually don't think it should be one, because profile pictures can also be hosted on Gravatar and Imgur is not only used for profile pictures.

Comment: fair enough. there's no *thumbnail* or *avatar* tag, so I couldn't add those to the other post, either. seems like there should be some way to improve the other post so that we might have found it when we each searched

Comment: There is an [avatar] tag, but it's a synonym of [profile-picture].

Comment: @ProgramFOX [is correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/profile-picture/synonyms), but there is a bug here on MSE that cause synonyms to not show in the tag autocomplete until you type the full word, hence you didn't see anything when typing avatar. (you probably didn't type the whole word)

Comment: fwiw, my avatar in the StackExchange ipad app is still broken.

Comment: This might be worth a different bug report, tagged properly.